# Python Challenge #3: Loop stops way too early

Tags: python, loops

I'm working on PythonChallenge #3. I've got a huge block of text that I have to sort through. I am trying to find a sequence in which the first and last three letters are caps, and the middle one is lowercase.

My function loops through the text. The variable block stores the seven letters that are currently being looped through. There's a variable, toPrint, which gets turned on and off based on whether the letters in block correspond to my pattern (AAAaAAA). Based on the last block printed according to my function, my loop stops early in my text. I have no idea why this is happening and if you could help me figure this out, that would be great.

```
text = """kAewtloYgcFQaJNhHVGxXDiQmzjfcpYbzxlWrVcqsmUbCunkfxZWDZjUZMiGqhRRiUvGmYmvnJ"""
words = []
for i in text:
    toPrint = True
    block = text[text.index(i):text.index(i)+7]
    for b in block[:3]:
        if b.isupper() == False:
            toPrint = False
    for b in block[3]:
        if b.islower() == False:
            toPrint = False
    for b in block[4:]:
        if b.isupper() == False:
            toPrint = False
    if toPrint == True and block not in words:
        words.append(block)
print (block)
print (words)
```

Comment: are you allowed to use regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## With Regex:

This is a really good time to use regex, it's super fast, more clear, and doesn't require a bunch of nested if statements.

```
import re
text = """kAewtloYgcFQaJNhHVGxXDiQmzjfcpYbzxlWrVcqsmUbCunkfxZWDZjUZMiGqhRRiUvGmYmvnJ"""
print(re.search(r"[A-Z]{3}[a-z][A-Z]{3}", text).group(0))
```

**Explanation of regex:**
[A-Z]{3] ---> matches any 3 uppercase letters
[a-z] -------> matches a single lowercase letter
[A-Z]{3] --->  matches 3 more uppercase letters

## Without Regex:

If you really don't want to use regex this is how you could do it:

```
text = """kAewtloYgcFQaJNhHVGxXDiQmzjfcpYbzxlWrVcqsmUbCunkfxZWDZjUZMiGqhRRiUvGmYmvnJ"""

for i, _ in enumerate(text[:-6]): #loop through index of each char (not including last 6)
    sevenCharacters = text[i:i+7] #create chunk of seven characters
    shouldBeCapital = sevenCharacters[0:3] + sevenCharacters[4:7] #combine all the chars that should be cap into list

    if (all(char.isupper() for char in shouldBeCapital)): #make sure all those characters are indeeed capital
        if(sevenCharacters[3].islower()): #make sure middle character is lowercase
            print(sevenCharacters)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, then according to my opinion there is no need of loop. My this simple code can find required sequence.

```
# Use this code

text = """kAewtloYgcFQaJNhHVGxXDiQmzjfcpYbzxlWrVcqsmUbCunkfxZWDZjUZMiGqhRRiUvGmYmvnJ"""

import re

print(re.findall("[A-Z]{3}[a-z][A-Z]{3}", text))
```

Comment: Sorry brother, When I was answering this question, there was no answer for this question.

Comment: This is slightly different. It returns all the 7-letter blocks that fit the criteria, whereas the other function only returned one. Thank you, this works very nicely!

Answer (score 0):

I think your first problem is that you are using `str.index()`. Like `find()`, the `.index()` method of a string returns the index of the *first* match that is found.

Thus, in your example, whenever you search for 'x' you will get the index of the first 'x' found, etc. You cannot successfully work with any character that is not unique in the string, or that is not the first occurrence of a repeated character.

In order to keep the same structure (which isn't necessary- there is an answer posted using enumerate that I prefer myself) I implemented a queuing approach with your block variable. Each iteration, a character is dropped from the front of block, while the new character is appended to the end.

I also cleaned up some of your needless comparisons with `False`. You will find that this is not only inefficient, it is frequently wrong, because many of the "boolean" activities you perform will not be on actual boolean values. Get out of the habit of spelling out `True/False`. Just use `if c` or `if not c`.

Here's the result:

```
text = """kAewtloYgcFQaJNhHVGxXDiQmzjfcpYbzxlWrVcqsmUbCunkfxZWDZjUZMiGqhRRiUvGmYmvnJ"""
words = []
block = '.' + text[0:6]
for i in text[6:]:
    block = block[1:] + i  # Drop 1st char, append 'i'
    toPrint = True
    for b in block[:3]:
        if not b.isupper():
            toPrint = False
    if not block[3].islower():
        toPrint = False
    for b in block[4:]:
        if not b.isupper():
            toPrint = False
    if toPrint and block not in words:
        words.append(block)
print (words)
```